# Silverlight how to start a RadRibbonBar in "IsCollapsed" mode - property is ReadOnly

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, telerik, telerik-radribbonbar

We have a Silverlight application with a RadRibbonBar at the top. The user can collapse it (not Visibility.Collapse) to just the menus with a double-click.

The `IsCollapsed` property is ReadOnly, but we need to retain the user preferences across runs of the app.

**How do you programmatically set the `IsCollapsed` state of a RadRibbonBar?**

### Result

Silly me (and shows that the documentation is a little hard to find/follow). I had to google "RadRibbonBar IsMinimised" to find the actual page: http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/telerik.windows.controls.ribbonbar-telerik.windows.controls.radribbonbar-isminimized.html

Thanks to Stephen McDaniel for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be confusing "Collapsing" a RibbonBar with the idea of "Minimizing" it.

Collapsing is something the RibbonBar does automatically when the window gets very small - which is why it's ready-only.  From the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radribbonbar-features-collapsing.html):

> RadRibbonBar supports collapsing, which means that the ribbon may
>   automatically collapse to save space when the application is resized
>   to a smaller size.

But what you are describing (double clicking to get just the menu) is called Minimizing.  From the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radribbonbar-features-minimization.html):

> RadRibbonBar supports minimization, which means that the ribbon may be
>   hidden so that only its tab headers remain visible. In this state,
>   more screen real estate is available to the client area of the window.

And luckily, controlling Minimization via code is very easy.  You can use the `IsMinimized` property:

> IsMinimized - use this property to set or get the current minimize
>   state of the ribbon.

So you should be using the IsMinimized property instead of IsCollapsed.

You can check out the documentation links I provided above for more information.

Comment: You are spot on the money (and the points). Shame nobody pointed out it was so simple before I put up the bounty :)